# Ruby array only storing last item during collect statement

Tags: ruby, rubymotion

I have a ruby method that queries a array through a search. From what is typed in the searchbar it appends that item to another array that shows on the screen. Below is my method:

```
@churches = ["UGBC", "Oak Ridge Baptist", "Calvary"]
@search_results = []


def search_for(text)
  @churches.collect do |church|
    if text == church
      @search_results << church
    end
  end
end
```

When the code is triggered the only object that is returned when searched is the last object in the array: "Calvary". If you search any of the other items it sends back an empty array. I have tried an each statement and a collect statement and nothing will work. How do I get it to append to the empty array with no matter what item I search on?

Comment: Working with side-effects is usually a bad idea, if besides that the operation done is not idempotent (`<<`), it's conceptually pretty bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the right method. I think Array#select is what you need. Also you might have to do a substring check for the text.

Here is an example

```
text = 'Ridge'

> churches.select{|c| c.include?(text)}
#=> ["Oak Ridge Baptist"]
```

Comment: The select method was exactly what I was looking for. Now I can append the results into a new array every time. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

What is your text value?. If you are performing text("Calvary") == church..  It matches one of the element of @churches.That @churches element alone store in @search_results. So storing last element.

Answer (score 0):

Your function returns the value of the last expression evaluated. That is the value of `@churches.collect`. That -- in turn -- is an array of the three values of the block:

```
search_for('UGBC')               # => [["UGBC"], nil, nil]
@search_results = []
search_for('Oak Ridge Baptist')  # => [nil, ["Oak Ridge Baptist"], nil]
@search_results = []
search_for('Calvary')            # => [nil, nil, ["Calvary"]]
@search_results = []
search_for('something else')     # => [nil, nil, nil]
```

The block yields `nil` in case of no match and `@search_result` with the found `church` appended in case of a match.

Note that your function modifies `@search_results`. So I reset it in order to hide the side-effects of previous runs.

An obvious fix to your function is to return `@search_results`:

```
def search_for(text)
  @search_results = []
  @churches.collect do |church|
    if text == church
      @search_results << church
    end
  end
  @search_results # or even: return @search_results
end
```

A better implementation returning the found element or `nil` is

```
def search_for(text)
  @churches.find { | c | c == text }
end
```